# find total surface area of solid using formula for surface area using integration

Tags: calculus

find the total surface area of solid which is formed when the region enclosed by 
$x^2+y^2=4$ in the first quadrant is rotated about $y=-1$.

Edit: I'm getting that on rotating this solid I'm getting 3 surfaces: outer surface, inner surface and the surface of a ring. Using integration, I have calculated the outer surface area. How should I calculate the surface area for the inner surface and ring part using integration?

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm getting that on rotating this solid I'm getting 3 surfaces: outer surface, inner surface and the surface of a ring. Using integration, I have calculated the outer surface area. How should I calculate the surface area for the inner surface and ring part using integration?

Comment: You can shift the entire region up by $1$ to rotate around the $x$-axis. Then you can use the formula for surface area to calculate the surface area of the whole thing ([surface area formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution)).

Comment: I don't think we can do that. We need to find the surface area as it is

Comment: But translations do not change areas. By far, this is the easiest method to find the surface area.

Answer (score 1):

First shift up the quarter circle to get $$x^2+(y-1)^2=4$$ for $0\le x\le 2.$ Then to get the area of the outer surface (by which I suppose you mean the one generated by the arc itself), solve for $y$ as a function of $x,$ then use the formula $$\int_0^2{2πy\sqrt{1+{y'}^2}\mathrm d x}$$ to find the area.

You can do that for the constant function $f(x)=1$ defined by the base of the quarter disk parallel to the $x$-axis to find the area of the inner surface area of the solid of revolution.

Finally, the last side generates a washer whose dimensions are available and thus you now have the three areas you needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have the equation of a circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$
Your answer is [here](http://www.phengkimving.com/calc_of_one_real_var/12_app_of_the_intgrl/12_07_areas_of_surf_of_revltn.htm#exa_05_01) showing the surface of a rotated circle which is a sphere: $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$. The link shows the integration steps needed to find $A=4\pi r^2$ where $r=2$. A comment noted that you were only looking for a quarter of a circle (first quadrant). The $z$ axis is orthogonal so it won't affect calculations for the $xy$ plane; we just divide the total area by $4$, that is $A=\pi r^2$ which is only coincidentally the same as the area of a whole cirle.

Comment: He's concerned only about a quarter circle, not the full thing.